# Why I am retrieving high value loss for neural network regression

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, regression, conv-neural-network

I have data in the following format consisting of 80 instances. I need to predict two-parameter latency and accuracy

```
   No   Model   Technique       Latency  Accuracy
0   1   Net     Repartition     31308.4   0.99   
1   2   Net     Connection      30338.2   0.79   
2   3   MobiNet Repartition     20360.1   0.89  

 predictors=data.drop(['Latency','Accuracy'], axis = 1)
    target=data[['Latency', 'Accuracy']]
    predictors_cat_converted=pd.get_dummies(predictors, prefix=['Model', 'Technique'])
    
    pre_norms = (predictors_cat_converted-predictors_cat_converted.mean()/predictors_cat_converted.std())
    
    def regression():
      model=Sequential()
      model.add(Dense(50, activation= 'relu',input_shape=(n_cols,)))
      model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))#hidden layer
      model.add(Dense(2))#output
    
      model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')
      return model
    
    model=regression()
    model.fit(pre_norms, target,validation_split=.3,epochs=100,verbose=1)
```

Output retrieving high value loss

```
    Epoch 1/100
    2/2 [==============================] - 1s 275ms/step - loss: 256321162.6667 - val_loss: 262150224.0000
    Epoch 2/100
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 23ms/step - loss: 246612645.3333 - val_loss: 262146176.0000
    Epoch 3/100
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 22ms/step - loss: 251778928.0000 - val_loss: 262142000.0000
    Epoch 4/100
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 26ms/step - loss: 252470826.6667 - val_loss: 262137664.0000
    Epoch 5/100
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 25ms/step - loss: 255799392.0000 - val_loss: 262133200.0000
    Epoch 6/100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have very less data, just 2 columns, 80 rows and 2 target variables. All you can do is:

1. Add more data.
2. Normalize your data and then feed it to the neural network.
3. If neural network not giving good accuracy, try Random Forest or XGBoost.

I also want to add one thing that is your neural network architecture is wrong. Dense layer with 2 outputs and a softmax activation isn't going to give you good result here. You have to use TensorFlow's `Funtional API` and make 1 input 2 output neural network architecture.

Comment: Thanks alot @AdarshWase, I will try Random Forect or XGBoost

Answer (score 0):

One of your target variables reaches quite big values. As shown in the excerpt of your data, "Latency" reaches values around 30,000 and 20,000.
Evidently if your model makes quite wrong predictions in the beginning, f.e. if it predicts "1" for your Latency, the MSE will be extremely high.

You could normalize your targets as you did with your inputs to make it easier for your network to learn the targets. Your MSE and hence your loss should be much smaller then